# Java highlight function selected jlist index name

Tags: java

I am trying to programmatically select an jlist index and also highlight it to emulate the mouse click.

This is the code I am using to select the index. It does set it, but I can't get the highlight effect that I need.  `brandsBgList.isSelectedIndex(Integer.valueOf(addmore));`

[image]

Comment: `jList1.setSelectedIndex(Integer.valueOf(addmore));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JList` method you're looking for is called `setSelectedIndex`.

```java
brandsBgList.setSelectedIndex(Integer.valueOf(addmore));
```

You are using `isSelectedIndex`.

Comment: yeah thanks mate, I got the answer from @devilshnd yday but thank you :)

Comment: @JohnnyD, no problem.  As a recommendation, when coding,  you can keep a browser window open, linked to the Java SE JavaDoc page.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/